# Posting and validating MVC CSRF Token with custom attribute in AngularJS not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, csrf, actionfilterattribute, filterattribute

I am developing a Web Application using Angular JS and ASP.NET MVC. I am having a problem with validating CSRF token. I asked a question dealing with CSRF token and AngularJS as well. But this question a little bit different. I am following this link now - http://techbrij.com/angularjs-antiforgerytoken-asp-net-mvc.

I created a Custom CSRF validation class like this

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class AngularValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        string cookieToken = String.Empty;
        string formToken = String.Empty;
        string tokenValue = request.Headers["RequestVerificationToken"];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenValue))
        {
            string[] tokens = tokenValue.Split(':');
            if (tokens.Length == 2)
            {
                cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
                formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
            }
        }
        AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                ValidateRequestHeader(filterContext.HttpContext.Request);
            }
            else
            {
                AntiForgery.Validate();
            }
        }
        catch (HttpAntiForgeryException e)
        {
            throw new HttpAntiForgeryException("Anti forgery token cookie not found"); // This line is throwing error
        }
    }           
}
```

Then I post like this in AngularJS:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: path,
    data: { Email : $scope.email, Password : $scope.password },
    headers: {
        'RequestVerificationToken': $rootScope.csrfToken
    }
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('success')
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('error')
});
```

It always throws this error

[image]

I commented in the code above where error is throwing. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Does the request have the tokens in the RequestVerificationToken header? You can use dev tools in your browser to check the sent request. Are the tokens received correctly in `ValidateRequestHeader()` when passing them to `AntiForgery.Validate`? What did you try to debug your code? Where exactly is it failing?

Comment: It is posting the value.